# Present different country to server using Android

Tags: java, android, youtube

I am trying to play **youtube** video URL in `videoView` or `WebView`. When I try to play it in `WebView`.  **Error**

**The website is not accessible.**

> The site you are trying to access contains content that is prohibited for Viewership in your country.

**I want to know how can i change my country representation using android so server thinks that I am from another country that supports Youtube.**

Is there any way using `Android`. And there are a lot of chrome plugins like browsec that do the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in this case, the Youtube server is blocking you, because your location. You will need to use a proxy in order to reach Youtube server from a different IP address located in another country.

Comment: how can i achieve it.

Comment: @Nepster there are several options, just write "private proxy" in Google, but automating it in an Android app would be more difficult.

Comment: Is there any other way to play youtube url in WebView or videoView

Comment: @Nepster you do not need to play "in other way", you need to request the video from a different IP address.